# Select Data from combo box and shows the information to it in List Box c#

Tags: c#, linq, combobox, listbox

I encountered some problem whereby when the user selects the selected name inside the combo box, the data linked with the names selected will show out in the list box. I have problem making into this method. The error falls here.

```
int selectLocStation = Convert.ToInt32(cbLocStation.SelectedValue);
```

Error: Unable to cast object of type'<>f_AnonymousType2'2 [System.String.System.Int32]'to type 'System.IConvertible'.

```
private void cbLocStation_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (satsEntities Setupctx = new satsEntities())
        {
            int selectLocStation = Convert.ToInt32(cbLocStation.SelectedValue);

            var query = (from db in Setupctx.requiredtimings
                         join timing t in Setupctx.timings on db.RequiredTimingID equals t.TimingID
                         where db.RequiredLocationStationID == selectLocStation
                         select new
                         {
                             t.Time2
                         }).ToList();

            List<TimeSpan> lstSelectedTime = new List<TimeSpan>();

            foreach (var a in query)
            {
                lstSelectedTime.Add((TimeSpan)a.Time2);
            }

            lstTime.DataSource = lstSelectedTime;
        }
    }
```

This is what I do to store data inside the combo box.

```
using (satsEntities Setupctx = new satsEntities())
        {
            var DeleteRT = (from DelRT in Setupctx.requiredtimings
                            join locationstationname ls in Setupctx.locationstationnames on DelRT.RequiredLocationStationID equals ls.locationstationID
                            select new { ls.locStatname, DelRT.RequiredLocationStationID }).Distinct().ToList();

            cbLocStation.DataSource = DeleteRT.ToList();
            cbLocStation.DisplayMember = "locStatname";
            cbLocStation.ValueMember = "RequiredLocationStationID";
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you init your combobox? Could you tell us what values does your combobox contain?

Comment: Let me show you the codes that I store the data inside the combo box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  private void Edit_TS_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (satsEntities Setupctx = new satsEntities())
        {
            var DeleteRT = (from DelRT in Setupctx.requiredtimings
                           join locationstationname ls in Setupctx.locationstationnames on DelRT.RequiredLocationStationID equals ls.locationstationID
                           select new {ls.locStatname, DelRT.RequiredLocationStationID}).Distinct().ToList();

            cbLocStation.DataSource = DeleteRT.ToList();
            cbLocStation.DisplayMember = "locStatname";
            cbLocStation.ValueMember = "RequiredLocationStationID";

        }
    }
```

Answer is here!

Answer (score 0):

if to string is available I would try this

```
int selectLocStation = Convert.ToInt32(cbLocStation.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

or this

```
int selectLocStation =Int32.Parse(cbLocStation.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

you can also try this

```
DataRowView drow = (DataRowView)cbLocStation.SelectedItem;
string str = drow.Row.ItemArray[0].ToString();
```

check if string has numbers and the convert it to int

you can also add databind

```
BindingContext oBC = new BindingContext();
    cbLocStation.BindingContext = oBC;
    cbLocStation.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("SelectedValue", DeleteRT, "RequiredLocationStationID", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

Comment: I tried your way and they prompt me another error saying that "Input string was not in the correct format".

Comment: @rookie  ohhh try to check if the string actually contains a number otherwise use int parse

Comment: I'm using Windows Form Application.

Comment: @rookie I think the problem is because you are using databind

Comment: You mean the DataSource that I used to bind the data in my combo right? I tried using others ways by using Items.Add but the selectedValue is different from my database thus cannot show any Data under the Selected name.

Comment: I have tried your way of databinding but the combo box do not have any data. It seems that "int selectLocStation = Convert.ToInt32(cbLocStation.SelectedValue);" cannot work with DataSource.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to convert the anonymous type from the query into timespan which is not possible since it doesn't implement the IConvertible. you can write a wrapper class and select that class in the query.

```
var query = (from db in Setupctx.requiredtimings
                         join timing t in Setupctx.timings on db.RequiredTimingID equals t.TimingID
                         where db.RequiredLocationStationID == selectLocStation
                         select new WrapperClass
                         {
                             Time = t.Time2
                         }).ToList();

public class WrapperClass
        {
            public DateTime Time { get; set; }
        }
```

where time is a DateTime you have defined in the wrapper class

Comment: What do you mean by writing a WrapperClass? Mind showing some examples? thanks!

Comment: select new returns an anonymous type, one that you can't do operations on such as the one you are trying to accomplish. instead according to your needs you should write a class that returns from the query. then you can work with the output.

Comment: I can't use DateTime because I'm using TimeSpan and if I changed the DateTime to TimeSpan still prompting errors.